# Function inside eval() is showing up undefined

Tags: javascript

I have defined a function inside eval() and was printing the type of function name. But instead of 'function', 'undefined' was printing.

```
<script>
if(1){
eval(function foo(){});
var k = typeof foo;
}
console.log(k)
</script>
```

I expected 'function' as output but got 'undefined'

Comment: If you don’t pass `eval` a string, it just returns what you pass it.

Answer (score 3):

The `eval()` function accepts a string, you have given a function expression instead. Pass the function expression as a string.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Syntax

```js
if (1) {
  eval('function foo(){}');
  var k = typeof foo;
}
console.log(k)
```

As per the docs:

> If the argument of eval() is not a string, eval() returns the argument
>   unchanged.